# converting time from '00:00:00.0000' to MM:SS mysql

Tags: mysql, epoch

After trying all solutions on StackOverflow, I still cant get my time to convert from what it is to mm:ss.

I have tried time_format,date_format,Substring,left,right.

my query is:

```
SELECT location,sec_to_time(AVG(time_to_sec(time_avg))) as timeAVG 
FROM test.test 
group by location
```

And the output is:

```
'zone1', '00:26:13.3333'
```

Or similar for other items is there all above methods that I try do convert the time but leave 0 in place of items I have removed e.g.

```
SELECT location,sec_to_time(AVG(time_to_sec(time_format(time_avg, '%i:%s')))) as timeAVG 
FROM test.test
group by location
```

Will return:

`'zone1', '26:13:20.0000'` same as date_format

`substring`,`left` and `right` all return same as the 1st value provided

If I run:

```
select location,TIME_FORMAT(time_avg,'%i:%s') 
from test.test 
group by location
```

It formats the time correctly to:

```
'zone1', '29:47'
```

But the query doesn't return the value I'm after.

Comment: `but the query doesnt return the value im after` what does this mean? It returns `29:47` which is `MM:SS`, that's exactly what you are looking for yes?

Comment: you want the fractional part in the last SQL statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select location,TIME_FORMAT(time_avg,'%i:%s.%f') from test.test group by location;
```